# "in" statement behavior in lists vs. strings

Tags: python, substring, iterable, in-operator

In Python, asking if a substring exists in a string is pretty straightforward:

```
>>> their_string = 'abracadabra'
>>> our_string = 'cad'
>>> our_string in their_string
True
```

However, checking if these same characters are "in" a list fails:

```
>>> ours, theirs = map(list, [our_string, their_string])
>>> ours in theirs
False
>>> ours, theirs = map(tuple, [our_string, their_string])
>>> ours in theirs
False
```

I wasn't able to find any obvious reason why checking for elements "in" an ordered (even immutable) iterable would behave differently than a different type of ordered, immutable iterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For container types such as lists and tuples,  `x in container` checks if `x` is an item in the container. Thus with `ours in theirs`, Python checks if `ours` is an item in `theirs` and finds that it is False.

Remember that a list could contain a list. (e.g `[['a','b','c'], ...]`)

```
>>> ours = ['a','b','c']    
>>> theirs = [['a','b','c'], 1, 2]    
>>> ours in theirs
True
```

Comment: `type(ours) != type(theirs[0])` vs. `type(our_string) == type(their_string[0])`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to see if 'cad' is in any of the strings in a list of strings? That would like something like:

```
stringsToSearch = ['blah', 'foo', 'bar', 'abracadabra']
if any('cad' in s for s in stringsToSearch):
    # 'cad' was in at least one string in the list
else:
    # none of the strings in the list contain 'cad'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Python documentation, https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html for sequences:

```
x in s  True if an item of s is equal to x, else False  (1)
x not in s  False if an item of s is equal to x, else True  (1)

(1) When s is a string or Unicode string object the in and not in operations act like a substring test.
```

For user defined classes, the `__contains__` method implements this `in` test.  `list` and `tuple` implement the basic notion.  `string` has the added notion of 'substring'.  `string` is a special case among the basic sequences.